# Convert old gene names (Affymetrix) to new gene names (RNAseq)

Tags: r, bioinformatics

I have two datasets, one of which is a microarray data set and another is RNAseq data for similar samples (a lot of cross over between them but they are NOT identical). The rows are samples and the columns are genes.

My problem is when I want to look at the same gene in each dataset, sometimes the gene names are different. The RNAseq data has the most genes in it, and as far as I can tell these are the most up to date gene names as well. Is there any way to convert the gene names in the microarray dataset to the same gene names as are in the RNAseq data easily?

Comment: you should post samples of your two datasets, otherwise it is difficult to understand what you need exactly and ultimately help

Comment: You'd better ask this question on other site like Biostar. And you may want to show a little part of your data.